# How to add action icons that are always visible to each record of a table that is very wide?

Tags: html, css, html-table

In my app I have a very large table with 20 columns that is sometimes wider than the entire monitor.

I have a column at the end named "Actions". This column enables users to edit/delete records in the table. Since the table is so wide, the user always ends up scrolling to the right before he can see the actions--this is tedious.

I want to change this behavior such that whenever the mouse hovers over a record 2 icons scroll down no matter where the scroll point is horizontally.

I have tried hacking the limitation of adding a div with absolute positioning to each record, but HTML does not allow divs inside of tr tags.

[image]

Comment: Can you make a demo in CodePen or JSFiddle?

Comment: Why not move the "Actions" column to be the first?

Comment: @McCaughan, because it would disappear once the user scrolls to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make two tables.

- one table for data columns
- one table with single column for action icon
- use Javascript to handle the icon click, get Row Index of the icon to determine which row in the data table will be affected
- Use CSS `Position:fixed`, `right:0px` property to set the one column table to the most right
- finally, give the one column table a `z-index` property larger than the data column

please let me know if you want further details

Comment: I was thinking about something similar but this might break if the heights of one of the rows becomes taller then the rest. I can use js to check for this. But this seems like a hack.

Comment: there is another solution to use absolute position but i don't like it since it might have issues in different resolutions.
to set the last column as position:absolute; right:120px so that the last column is always on 120px from the right

Answer (score 0):

You can use focus() to have the parent container scroll to your action button.

Here is an illustration. jQuery is not necessary but it makes things easier. (http://jsfiddle.net/rLc7S/):

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("TABLE").on("mouseover", function() {
        jQuery(this).find("BUTTON").focus();
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#container {
    width:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <table style="border:1px solid red;">
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td class="actions">
            <button type="button">action 1</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td class="actions">
            <button type="button">action 2</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</html>
```

Edit: this one is a bit less jumpy http://jsfiddle.net/rLc7S/1/

Comment: That's actually a great idea! Although it's a bit disturbing.

Comment: Ya, I found it got a bit difficult to navigate with the rows always focussing on the button. Maybe I'll modify this to be a bit more user friendly.

Comment: Added another fiddle but it's just a shot in the dark. Really, I just wanted to illustrate that if you .focus() the button, your container will scroll to it. There is probably a better way to do that in your case than in my illustration. Perhaps a click somewhere on the row could trigger the focus...